# Implementation details of Findbugs

Tags: findbugs

I am reading findbugs source code to have a clear understanding on the implementation of Findbugs.I have some problems:

1 There are too many main classes in the source files .Which one should I choose to debug.

2 As I know ,Findbugs traverses the AST and find the bug pattern,if it matches,bug reported.And where is the definition of bug patterns?

Is anyone can help me ?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions of the bugs are in two xml files in the etc directory `findbugs.xml` and `messages.xml`

All the detectors are in the edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detectors package. The detectors for the most part are implemented as a listener pattern. Callbacks are called by findbugs-proper when various parts of class are scanned.

The main 'controller' loop for findbugs is FindBugs2.analyzeApplication